# Is there any Maps API to change street name on particular map?

Tags: google-maps, maps, openstreetmap, yandex-api

Is it possible to allow user to change the name of the streets in embedded map? Does any API provide such feature? For example, I want to allow users to make their 'alternative map' and get link to it.

Comment: Are you talking about correcting street names or fantasy street names?

Comment: Fantasy street names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OpenStreetMap this is possible of course but requires some work and suitable hardware. You have to [server your own tiles](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) and provide access to the underlying database with the help of one of the many different [editors](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Editing) or via a custom solution. If you don't want to serve the whole world you can also fill your database with one of the available [extracts](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Extract).

Comment: I wrote to one dude from OSM community, he responded very quickly and gave me the same answer :)